# Python Pandas group by month and year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following,

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['AAA','2019-01-01', 10], ['AAA','2019-01-02', 20],
        ['AAA','2019-02-01', 30], ['AAA','2019-02-02', 40],
        ['BBB','2019-01-01', 50], ['BBB','2019-01-02', 60],
        ['BBB','2019-02-01', 70],['BBB','2019-02-02', 80]]

dfx = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['NAME', 'TIMESTAMP','VALUE'])

  NAME   TIMESTAMP  VALUE
0  AAA  2019-01-01     10
1  AAA  2019-01-02     20
2  AAA  2019-02-01     30
3  AAA  2019-02-02     40
4  BBB  2019-01-01     50
5  BBB  2019-01-02     60
6  BBB  2019-02-01     70
7  BBB  2019-02-02     80
```

I am trying to do a sum on the column 'VALUE' grouped by MONTH and YEAR in the 'TIMESTAMP' and 'NAME' columns.

So the final desired output is,

```
  NAME   TIMESTAMP  VALUE SUM
0  AAA  2019-01-01     10  30
1  AAA  2019-01-02     20  30
2  AAA  2019-02-01     30  70
3  AAA  2019-02-02     40  70
4  BBB  2019-01-01     50 110
5  BBB  2019-01-02     60 110
6  BBB  2019-02-01     70 150
7  BBB  2019-02-02     80 150
```

How do I get this output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and 
[`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
d = pd.to_datetime(dfx['TIMESTAMP'])
dfx['SUM'] = (dfx.groupby(['NAME', 
                           dfx['TIMESTAMP'].dt.year, 
                           dfx['TIMESTAMP'].dt.month])['VALUE']
                 .transform('sum'))
```

Or month period by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
dfx['SUM'] = (dfx.groupby(['NAME', dfx['TIMESTAMP'].dt.to_period('m')])['VALUE']
                 .transform('sum'))
```

---

```
print (dfx)
  NAME   TIMESTAMP  VALUE  SUM
0  AAA  2019-01-01     10   30
1  AAA  2019-01-02     20   30
2  AAA  2019-02-01     30   70
3  AAA  2019-02-02     40   70
4  BBB  2019-01-01     50  110
5  BBB  2019-01-02     60  110
6  BBB  2019-02-01     70  150
7  BBB  2019-02-02     80  150
```